# Passing values between Asp.Net core files

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm creating a system for some of our partners. It will be controlled by values in the URL which will then set a cookie that persists their information.
I have wrapped this in a view component, called by the layout page. It returns a model, with information such as override CSS files. This works fine.

There is some more information here, such as the partner name, that I would now like to pass to the layout page and some other pages.
I tried adding this to the `ViewBag`, but it seems the order of execution is wrong.

Is there a better way to do this or something I'm missing?

I've seen in previous versions of MVC, you could create an input and then use `@Request` but this doesn't seem to exist in ASP.Net core.